# How tell if a polyhedron contains a lattice point

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, polyhedra, integer-lattices, integer-programming

So given a polyhedron

$Ax \le b$

Is there an Algorithm or formula to determine whether said polyhedron contains a lattice point (integer point)

I was thinking a couple things:

1. brute force neighborhood search (I don't like this idea)
2. Try to prove that at least 1 unit cube (of same dimension as polyhedron) can be contained in polyhedral space. Aka check if all dimensions between 2 faces $\ge$ 1
3. #2 doesn't always work so I need a fail-safe.

Has this been done before? I am not interested in finding the point, I just merely wish to know of one is present.

Answer (score 1):

This is called [Integer Linear Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_linear_programming). Note that the problem of determining whether $Ax\leq b$ contains a lattice point is asymptotically basically as hard as a maximization function with the same parameters. This problem is NP-hard, so it is expected that there is no polynomial time algorithm for it.

**Edit:** ILP can be reduced to this using binary search methods. We start by finding the maximum $B$ and minimum $b$ of the relaxed LP problem (if the set $Ax\leq b$ is unbounded, other bounds are needed which I will not discuss here). We can determine whether there is an integer solutions with $f(x)\ge c$ by checking whether the polytope $-f(x)\leq -c, Ax\leq b$ contains an integer point. Using this we can in polynomial time (assuming calls to the satisfiability routine run in constant time) get any exponential accuracy for the integer maximum.

Comment: Not exactly. ILP consists in maximizing a function with integer variables. What the person is asking is a decision criterion for the presence of an integer point. Maybe ILP is polynomial-time reducible to this (I don't know), do you have the reduction?

Comment: @Antoine ILP consists of maximizing a function with integer variables, subject to a constraint of the form $Ax\leq b$. As my remark states, this is essentially the same problem as deciding whether $Ax\leq b$ has an integer solution. This can easily be seen using cutting-plane techniques.

Comment: I just edited my comment to ask you for the reduction. Thank you!

Comment: @Antoine Hope that helps. My reduction is only to arbitrarily accurate approximations of the maximum. This gives you the precise maximum if the satisfiability algorithm also returns a witness, which I think any satisfiability algorithm can be easily converted to do.

Comment: When people say they can count the number of points contained in a polyhedron in poly-time does that not mean determining if a problem is solvable can be accomplished in polynomial time